# Cannot find symbol hasNextInt for a java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

I am learning Java by myself and I have come across a problem that I would like to tackle. Here is the problem:

> Write a class named `Calculator` with a method `int sum(String s)`. String `s` contains a set of integers separated by white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines). Return the sum of the integers.
>
> You can use a `Scanner` object to solve this problem. Create a `new Scanner(s)` and store it in a variable, say `in`. Then, use `in.hasNextInt()` to control a while loop. Each iteration of the while loop uses `in.nextInt()` to get the next integer from the String `s`. Accumulate this integer into a variable and return that variable when the loop exits.
>
> You may use a main method to test your method by creating an instance of the `Calculator` class and calling `sum(…)` with several combinations of values using that instance.

---

My code so far is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calculator{
    public int sum(String s){
        new Scanner(s);
        String in = s;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            s = in.nextInt();
        }
        return(0);
    }
}
```

I am not yet finished the course, but I am getting an error saying that it

> cannot find symbol : method hasNextInt()

Why? I am not quite sure what to do from this point onwards, so what should I do? Has `s` been stored into `in` correctly?

Comment: hasNextInt is not part of String!!!

Comment: @StefanBeike no need to add so many !!! ;-) Though you are completely right - be polite (what a rhyme haha :)

Comment: Eager to learn, and showed the code and the error. Definitely adding an upvote for that alone. If everyone did this in S.O. it'd be so much better. Can't add an answer as there's good ones below! Just a small point to the author: have a look at the javadocs for Scanner and String etc, it's a lot to take in but they get easier and can be a A BIG help going forward. Good luck with your programming :)

Comment: When you say "new", for instance `new Car()`, it's like acquiring a car. However, to use that car you still need the keys. That's what the variable assignment before the '=' is for. So saying `Volvo myCar = new Volvo()` gets you a new car, and says that `myCar` is the key to that Volvo. You can then use `myCar` to access the various things that car can do. Your variable `s` is the key to the string you are using. In this case, you just need a key to access what your `new Scannner()` can do (hence the `myScanner` in TanisDLJ's answer).

Comment: Another point to add, try to think of a more constructive title post.

Comment: @RossC I disagree. While this question is properly written and has all technical elements of a good question, it is a trivial mistake which should IMO be closed within seconds with a single comment explaining the error (like Stefan Beike's). 10 answers on this question only show how StackOverflow is a blind reputation hunt for some people.

Comment: @Dariusz I didn't look on it like that, and I take your point on board. I guess I'm weary from the usual 'write me an app that makes me a million dollars as I'm too lazy to bother' type posts that are spreading lately. The reputation hunt is out of control for sure, and I even find myself having to hold back from certain posts as they are for the wrong reason, and may not be that helpful. It's a double edged sword for sure.

Comment: @Dariusz or perhaps the massive amounts of answers are a sign that the SO community is willing to help everyone and anyone out. It can be frustrating to come across an error when you first start programming and cannot figure it out. Perhaps instead of criticizing the community for these actions, you should praise its willingness to help out fellow coders, amateurs and professionals alike.

Comment: @RossC see above if you want.

Answer (score 58):

Your variable declaration,

```
new Scanner(s);
String in = s;
```

Is quite wrong. You have to store the scanner in a variable. That means:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(s);
```

Then

```
while (myScanner.hasNextInt())
```

Answer (score 17):

Just creating a `new Scanner(s)` won't do much if you don't store it somewhere. The assignment seems to be asking you to store *it* (as opposed to `s`) in a variable called `in`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(s);
```

After that, you shouldn't ever have to deal with `s` directly again: the `Scanner` can do the work for you.

In your code, `s` is a `String`, so it doesn't have methods like `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()`. You should be calling those on `in` which should be a `Scanner` (this is the direct cause of the error).

Answer (score 5):

You are calling the method on a `String`.

You need to call the `hasNextInt()` method on `Scanner`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
   int i = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `hasNextInt()` method on [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner) object instead of String object `s`.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    int i = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {

       i = sc.nextInt();

     }
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new Scanner(s) won't do anything. You need to store it in some object of the Scanner class:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(s);
```

After that, the Scanner will do the work for you.

Also, String doesn't have methods like hasNextInt() and nextInt(). You need to access these methods with the Scanner object and lastly you need to close the Scanner:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Abc{

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     String s = "Hello, World!";
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

     while (scanner.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextInt());
     }
     scanner.close();
  }
}
```

For reading an input, you can also use BufferedReader.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use the method `hasNextInt()` on your String Object 's'.

There is no such method for String Objects. Therefore the error is correct.

I assume you would like to use the Scanner, so you should create a new Scanner object:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
```

You need to store the scanner object in a variable - otherwise you will lose the Scanner object and cannot use it. It's like building a cool gadget, but forget where you stored it in your house.

Then you can use the method

```
scanner.hasNextInt()
```

which is part of the Scanner and does what you want.
Looping around with that should now work better.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the Scanner incorrectly.
Visit the Javadoc for Scanner [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It provides some examples

Here is an update to your code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
   int i = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the `Scanner` object in some variable and then use `hasNextInt` from that like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class calculator{
  public int sum(String s){
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(s);
    int total = 0;
    while (myScanner.hasNextInt()) {
      total += myScanner.nextInt();
    }
    return(total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Point 1.

Writing `new Scanner(s);` will execute the Scanner constructor and creates an object.

But not assigning it to any variable of the same type will end up in losing this object from your reach within the memory. Any you will not be able to refer/use it later.

Now Point 2,

As object `s` is of type `String` and the String class does not have a definition of `hasNextInt()` hence you end up with the error `cannot find symbol : method`

Point 3,

`hasNextInt()` is a property of class `Scanner`. Hence, if you create an object of class `Scanner` and properly associate with a variable of the same type, you could use it straight away. E.g.,

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(s);
if(scnr.hasNextInt())
..
....
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s = "";

        // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

        // call the method
        while (scanner.hasNext()) 
        {
            // check if the scanner's next token is an int
            System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNextInt());

            // print what is scanned
            System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
        }

        // close the scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```